# Conditional style in tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to make tmux give me an indication of whether the prefix key was pressed.

```
set-option status-left '#{?client_prefix,Prefix,------} [#S] '
```

seemed to work, but it takes up space in the status bar that I feel could be used better (it also so longer that this interferes with the list of windows, but that could probably be solved if I wanted to go that way). Instead I tried to change the background of the session name, which can be done permanently with

```
set-option status-left-style 'bg=white'
```

so I tried combining those into

```
set-option status-left-style '#{?client_prefix,bg=white,}'
```

but that just makes tmux say "Bad style". So what is the correct syntax for doing that?

(I'm on Debian Bullseye and have installed tmux from the available package there, so I have a 3.1 if version matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do fairly easily is leave the style alone, but provide an attribute in your original setup instead of the string. This attribute will last until the end of the left status if there are no further attributes.
See under STYLES: *embedded styles may be specified in format options... by enclosing them in '#[' and ']'.*

```
set-option status-left '#{?client_prefix,#[bg=white],} [#S] '
```